# PAD JQuery - inner text in sibling of a parent

Tags: jquery-selectors, power-automate-desktop

I am using Power Automate Desktop to get information from a dynamically generated website. The elements go very deep and they don't mostly have usable handles, so I need to use the inner text to navigate around the document.

I am able to get to the static text element with `label:contains("static text")`, the hidden one with `label:contains("static text") + div` but I can't seem to be able to get to the one I get.

I tried `label:contains("static text"):parent() + div` but this returns the hidden static text as well for some reason. Interestingly, getting text from `label:contains("static text"):parent():parent()` returns the visible static text and `label:contains("static text"):parent():parent():nth-child(2)` cannot be found...

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <label>
              STATIC TEXT I CAN FIND
            </label>
            <div>
              HIDDEN STATIC TEXT I DON'T CARE ABOUT
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div 3x>
              <li>
                <div 3x>
                  <ul></ul>
                  <div>
                    DYNAMIC TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$("label:contains('STATIC TEXT I CAN FIND')").closest('div').parent().next().find('ul').next().html()
```

or

```
$("div > div > div > ul > li:eq(1) > div > div").html();
```